# too many request in a day? Gmailapp in a google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

if i'm not wrong, the daaily limits should be 20000 call per day. I have the following running scripts that do emails searchs:

```
3 that run every 5 minutes
3 that run every 10 minutes
1 that runs every 30 minutes
1 that runs every 60 minutes
13 that run once per day
```

If i do the maths, considering 10 calls to Gmailapp inside every script (actually, the script that call it the most call it 7 times), I got:

`10*(3*60/5*24+3*60/10*24+1*60/30*24+1*60/60*24+13)=13810`

which is under the daily limit.

Any idea of what is going on?

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: too many request in a day

Comment: You say you have multiple calls, can you post the code?

Comment: hi, i got the error in all my scripts. Usually is `var threads = Gmailapp.search("someSearch");`

Comment: You may refer with this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) regarding daily quotas. You can confirm the current on the Quota Limits tab of the [Apps Script Dashboard](https://script.google.com/a/google.com/dashboard). From this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42322924), maybe it was still under the span of 24 hours, hence you got a daily limit exceed error. Try implementing [Exponential Backoff](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads#exp-backoff) which may be a good strategy for handling those errors.